# Is it possible to have a register a handler for a double file extension in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In my application, it would be convenient to be able to define file extensions with two parts, such as `*.wav.myapp`, `*.mp3.myapp`, to indicate that these are files that are based on `wav` or `mp3` files, but with wrapper logic provided by my app. Then I'd like to register my app as a handler for these types, but taking into account the part of the filename *before* the final `myapp` extension, so I could, for instance, show different Explorer icons for `*.wav.myapp` and `*.mp3.myapp`, even though they both have `myapp` in the final position.

Is this possible>

Comment: Have you tried it? You can manually add file extensions in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

The extension is usually considered the string of characters following the *final* period.  My suggestion to get the functionality you want is to use an underscore instead of a period in your extension. You will then be creating multiple distinct extensions: `.wav_myapp` and `.mp3_myapp` for example.

Comment: Actually, that would probably work just as well and avoid file extension issues. Thanks. And welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. I’m glad I could be of use.